# How can I edit the ItemContainerStyle of the items of a ListView control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem, itemcontainerstyle

I want to be able to edit the ItemContainerStyle of the items of a ListView control such that I can modify how selected items appear. I've read that one can edit a copy of the generic ItemContainerStyle by opening up the Document Outline window, right clicking the ListView control in the outline, and selecting *Edit Additional Templates > Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) > Edit a Copy.* However, Visual Studio does not give me the option to *Edit a Copy* as demonstrated here: [Demonstration of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyQA9.gif).

**Details**

- I'm using .NET 6.0 and Visual Studio 2022
- Editing a copy does not work in Visual Studio Blend either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio will give one the option of editing a copy of the ItemContainerStyle of items of a ListBox but not of items of a ListView.